# Input error in Python (EOF error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I have this error in many solutions.I went through many answers on this topic but could not resolve the problem.I could only figure out that problem could be in taking input from a single input file where the whole input string  is taken in one input call and displays EOF error on second raw input call.

```
def change(a,b,l):
alist = []
blist = []
for m in range(0,26):
    alist.append(0)
    blist.append(0)
for i in a:
    alist[l[i]] += 1
for j in b:
    blist[l[j]] += 1
common = 0
for i in range(0,26):
    dif = (alist[i] - blist[i])
    if (dif != alist[i]):
        common += min(alist[i],blist[i])
total = (min(len(a),len(b)) - common) + abs(len(a) - len(b))
return total

test = int(raw_input())
ans = []
l = {}
for i in range(65,91):
    l[chr(i)] = i - 65
for i in range(0,test):
    a = str(raw_input())
    b = str(raw_input())
    ans = ans + [change(a,b,l)]
for j in ans:
    print j
```

It would be a great help if someone could describe how to take input at above mentioned multiple times from a single input file.

Comment: raw_input is already a string

Comment: also, instead of `int(raw_input())`, you should use `input()`. Please, give us example input

Comment: could you link the spoj problem?

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/EDIST/

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you want input from files, and not a terminal, you can use the `readline()` function of file objects. Example:

```
import sys

def test(f):
    num = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(num):
        a = int(f.readline())
        b = int(f.readline())
        print a, b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(sys.stdin)
```

You might also want to actually use the end of file as a marker for end of input. In your example you may not for instance require to get the number of records in the first line, but just go on until you hit EOF.